# show JSON data in d3.js rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, d3.js

This is taking me hours. It would be great if someone could show me exactly how to do this..

All Im trying to do is pass a JSON object to a html.erb page with an ajax call for a d3.js graph.  Most of the explanations i have found use the json file whereas my setup uses a JSON object.

My code is as below: the model (user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relationships
end

class User
  def self.including_relationships
    User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.user_id").select("users.name, relationships.user_id, relationships.followsid,users.value").each_with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |a, obj| 
      obj['nodes'] << a.slice('name')
      obj['links'] << a.slice('user_id', 'followsid', 'value')
    end
  end
end
```

The controller: user_controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

def index
  render :json =>  User.including_relationships
end

def data
  render :json =>  User.including_relationships
end
```

my routes.rb is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'user/data' => 'user#data'
  resources :user
end
```

The view (index.html.erb)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic HTML5 Template</title>
  <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script src="example.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET', 
  url: 'localhost:3000/user/index', 
  success: function(data) {
    var miserables = data
  }
})

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json(miserables, function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

</script>

</script>

</body>
</html>


    end
```

There are no errors, however all I am returned is a JSON formatted data. I would like the view to use the JSON object from

```
 render :json =>  User.including_relationships
```

and I though that putting it in the ajax script as

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET', 
      url: 'localhost:3000/user/index', 
      success: function(data) {
        var miserables = data
      }
    })
```

would be the way. But it isn't. I don't seem to be successfully pasing the JSON object to the ajax I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the jquery `$.ajax` here, just call it with `d3.json`.  d3 doesn't care if it's a file or an API, as long as it returns valid JSON:

```
d3.json('localhost:3000/user/index', function(error, graph) {

   // rest of graph code...

}
```

Comment: OK that simplifies things but I only get the JSON returned and not the view when I call /user/data or /user. How can I get the view called with the JSON?

Comment: @SebastianZeki, I don't understand the question.  You go to a URL it renders the view, the JavaScript in the view makes the AJAX call, when that completes, you draw the plot.

Comment: Thats what the code should be doing. But instead I just get the JSON data when I call the view. I dont understand why I don't get the JSON passed into the view so I can see a graph

Comment: @SebastianZeki, I'm not a rails guy, but `def index
  render :json =>  User.including_relationships
end`, this should return the view, no?  You have it returning JSON and doing the same thing as `def data`

Comment: Yes the def index should be returning the view but for some reason it doesnt and I just get the JSON instead. Perhaps it's my routes that are wrong but I don't think so. I've removed the def data- it doesn't make any difference to seeing the index page JSON though

Comment: @SebastianZeki, did you change `def index` to return the view?  The code above returns the JSON.

Comment: Oh. No it is left as json. I assumed the render json produced a json data object which would get included in the javascript in the view. Do you think I need to change the render?

Comment: You want to render a normal view; you want to then create your own method (well you do have the data call) - then in your view you just request /data).  I've got this working myself if you still need help (though I imagine it's been two months so you've probably figured it out).